# HTTP Status 902 - No such conversation

Tags: http, tomcat

I was working with a colleague doing some work that involves passing callback URL's from my module to his. Because of some misconfiguration on his side, the call back URL was different and it called a URL from his server, not mine. Appart that we fixed the error, during that misconfigured callback I got this response (which I've never seen before):

```
HTTP Status 902 - No such conversation
```

Just out of curiosity I googled around and can not find any specification or description of this HTTP status code, and I always thought that status codes only went from 1XX to 5XX (As explained in [Section 10 of the HTTP 1.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

Any idea where I can find an official (or not) spec that describes this?

FYI the server in question is a Tomcat 7.0.25

**EDIT:** Including image of the response

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this comes from Tomcat and not some other library (or even your own code) setting this response code?

Comment: @mindas Our code is not generating this response so I'm digging into all the libraries included that get a reference to the responde to see which exactly is putting this, but still can't find it. I dug before into the coyote sourcecode and couldn't find any reference to a 902 response, so I'm still digging. The web app uses `spring-webmvc`but I'm not sure if that's relevant yet

Comment: You wrote: "the call back URL was different and it called a URL from his server, not mine." Could the 902 code come from an application that was called by mistake on his server ? Do you have access to his source code ? It looks like someone got creative and decided to invent some custom status code for his internal needs.

Comment: @DavidLevesque it is exactly that and caught me off guard. I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for all the buzz but it turned out that a re-used internal company library is the one responsible for this, so **it is NOT related to Tomcat, nor Spring nor anything**. It is simply a proprietary company response code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official spec defining this. (You can see the list of registered status codes here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml)

Comment: Thanx @JulianReschke, but it would be interesting to see anything, official or not, that describes this