# I have a web server Apache setup question

Tags: apache, weblogic

Good morning . For the first time I have written to stackoverflow.

Currently we have a running server. We are using Apache as the web server and WebLogic 10.3.6 as the WAS server.

There is a problem here ... The WAS server has an action that generates a specific error code when accessing it directly. This particular error code is the 902 error code.
When you log in again, you will be given an error code of 902. If you access WAS directly, it will return error code 902.
However, when you access the web server (domain address), it will return a 500 error code instead of 902. Obviously this seems to be a problem with setting up a web server. I do not know where to return the 500 error code instead of the 902 error code.
Do you have any of these in your Apache configuration? I did not set up my own web server but I did not know that someone else was going out.

If you have a similar experience, please help. Thank you.

Attach a photo caputured  by Developer Tools.

[image]

Comment: 403 == `HTTP server to indicate that the server understood the request, but will not fulfill it`.  902 is returned by application servers, but Apache does not send that code out to the client.

Comment: @Nic3500 How do I get the 902 error code from Apache?

Comment: You cannot, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42355 and to a lesser degree https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835453/http-status-902-no-such-conversation.  These codes are not part of the RFC.